# superPower function from ES5 to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static-methods, arrow-functions

I have this function called superPower that takes an array of numbers, and returns a number. This number is created from taking each element multiplied by 10 to the power of its index position in the array, and then adding each elements together.

This is the ES5 version I need to refactor to ES6

```
 ArrayFunctions.superPower = function(array){
 return array.reduce(function(sum, number, index){
 return sum + (number * (Math.pow(10, index)));
 });
};
```

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
static superPower (array) {
  return array.reduce(((sum, number, index) => sum + number + index ) {
  return (sum + (number => number ** (10, index) ));
  });
}
```

Find bellow the complete code:

```js
class ArrayFunctions {
  constructor () {
  }
  static printSpecial (array) {
    return array.join(" --- ");
  }
  static doubleArray (array) {
      return array.map(number => number * 2);
  }
  static superPower (array) {
  //   return array.reduce( ((sum, number, index) => sum + number + index); {
  //     return sum + (number * (Math.pow(10, index)));
  // });
  }
}

// Method to refactor 

ArrayFunctions.superPower = function(array){
  return array.reduce(function(sum, number, index){
    return sum + (number * (Math.pow(10, index)));
  });
};

// Here I am testing how to refactor it
// ArrayFunctions.superPower = function(array){
// return array.reduce(((sum, number, index) => sum + number + index ) {
//   return (sum + (number => number ** (10, index) ));
// });
// };
```

Comment: I will provide the whole context , you are right @mplungjan

Comment: @RobG I jsut added an snippet to show you the whole context . I am testing my refactoring outside of the class body before having it working. After it works I will delate the code and add it to the class body.

Comment: What is the expected improvement of going from ES5 to 6 other than not working in older browsers

Comment: "*I need to refactor to ES6*" - Why? There's no good reason to change good working ES6 code to different ES6 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like:

```
ArrayFunctions.superPower = function(array){
 return array.reduce((sum, number, index) => {
   return sum+number*Math.pow(10, index);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: @randseed1724 You should accept an answer if no further help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```js
ArrayFunctions = {};
ArrayFunctions.superPower = (array => array.reduce(
  (sum, number, index) => sum + number * 10 ** index), 0)
);

console.log(ArrayFunctions.superPower([1,2,3]));
```

That won't run in my current Safari as it doesn't support the exponentiation operator `**`, I need to use:

```js
ArrayFunctions = {};
ArrayFunctions.superPower = (array => array.reduce(
  (sum, number, index) => sum + number * Math.pow(10, index), 0)
);

console.log(ArrayFunctions.superPower([1,2,3]));
```

Used in a class declaration one return is required as you can't use arrow functions to define static methods:

```js
class ArrayFunctions {
  constructor(){}

  static superPower (array) {
    return array.reduce((sum, number, index) => sum + number * Math.pow(10, index),0);
  }
}

console.log(ArrayFunctions.superPower([1,2,3]));
```

However if class syntax is to be used simply to create methods of an object, then it's hard to justify it over:

```js
var arrayFunctions = {
  superPower : (array) => array.reduce((sum, number, index) => sum + number * Math.pow(10, index), 0)
};
    
console.log(arrayFunctions.superPower([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: That depends on your criteria for "right". If you're using arrow functions, there's no need for *return* (in this case) as one-line functions return the value of their statement by default. And there's no need for the *function* keyword either.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that my porpoise is to use it inside the class body.  I can't use your solution inside the class body, it doesn't work.

Comment: @randseed1724—it does if you write it correctly. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to my class body and it worked perfectly:

```
 return array.reduce((sum, number, index) => {
 return sum+number*Math.pow(10, index);
```

now it is like this:

```
class ArrayFunctions {
 constructor () {
 }
  static printSpecial (array) {
   return array.join(" --- ");
  }
  static doubleArray (array) {
   return array.map(number => number * 2);
  }
  static superPower (array) {
   return array.reduce((sum, number, index) => {
   return sum+number*Math.pow(10, index);
 });
 }
 }

 module.exports = ArrayFunctions;
```

Thank you @PHPglue

Comment: Accepting the previously-given answer is probably sufficient.

Comment: @DaveNewton What exactly do you mean or suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Never not use a `class` with `static` functions only, use an object literal! (Or just use only named exports, if you wanted to default-export the module object)

Your code should become

```
const ArrayFunctions = {
  printSpecial(array) {
    return array.join(" --- ");
  }
  doubleArray(array) {
    return array.map(number => number * 2);
  }
  superPower(array) {
    return array.reduce((sum, number, index) =>
      sum + number * 10 ** index;
    );
  }
};
```

Notice that you can also improve the efficiency of the code by doing a `reduceRight` instead of the `reduce`, and improve the reliability by passing `0` for the start so that the function returns `0` instead of throwing an exception:

```
return array.reduceRight((acc, number) => number + 10 * acc, 0);
```